# CSS Vertical-align: middle not working as expected

Tags: html, css

This is probably a very simple question, however I have been unable to find the answer...

I have 5 images, the first is 200 x 100 px, the other four are 50 x 50px. I'm trying to vertically align them centrally using `vertical-align: middle` but its not working as expected.

This is my HTML:

```
        <header>
            <div id="sm_icons">
                <img src="imgs/logo.png" alt="Site Logo" />
                <img class="sm_img" src="icons/aquaicons/Email.png" alt="Link to Home page">
                <img class="sm_img" src="icons/aquaicons/Aquicon-Facebook.png" alt="Link to Facebook page">
                <img class="sm_img" src="icons/aquaicons/Aquicon-GooglePlus.png" alt="Link to Google+ page">
                <img class="sm_img" src="icons/aquaicons/Aquicon-Twitter.png" alt="Link to Twitter page">
            </div>
        </header>
```

I have successfully vertically aligned the images using the following CSS:

```
.sm_img {
position: relative;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
left: 400px;
}

#sm_icons > img{
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

My question is, why does the below not work as an alternative to the above?

```
.sm_img {
position: relative;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
left: 400px;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Should `vertical-align: middle` not place the four images in the middle of the parent element, in this case the `#sm_icons`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I simplified your code a bit to demonstrate how the `vertical-align` property affects inline images.

In Example 1, `vertical-align: middle` is applied to every image within the parent block, including the large image to the left.  In this case, all the images are vertically positioned such that the middle of each image is on the baseline of the line box containing the content (images).

In Example 2, `vertical-align: middle` applies only to the small images, and by default, the large image uses `vertical-align: baseline`.  In this case, the bottom edge of the large image is along the baseline of the line box and the smaller images are positioned so that their vertical mid-point is on the  baseline.

Your two CSS rules are not equivalent.  The first affects all the images and the second affects only the small images, hence two different results.

The `vertical-align` property controls how inline elements are positioned with respect to the baseline of the line box.

However, within a table-cell (either using `td` or `display: table-cell`), the vertical-align property will give you the behavior you initially expected.  What is a bit misleading is that the same property name has two very behaviors depending on the context, but that is how the CSS specification happens to be written.

```css
.sm_icons img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.sm_icons_v2 .sm_img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<b>Example 1</b><br>
<div class="sm_icons">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
  <img class="sm_img" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
  <img class="sm_img" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
  <img class="sm_img" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
  <img class="sm_img" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
</div>
<br><br>
<b>Example 2</b><br>
<div class="sm_icons_v2">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
  <img class="sm_img" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
  <img class="sm_img" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
  <img class="sm_img" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
  <img class="sm_img" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Marc, the explanation about how the baseline works also answered a few other questions I had.

Answer (score 3):

`vertical-align` will not vertically center elements within `block` level element, which is what you are attempting to do (it seems).

It's confusing because the property *is* named **`vertical-align`**, but it functions at the `inline` or line(?) level. Check out this [fiddle for an example](http://jsfiddle.net/4u8jm4ng/1/).

What you are after is vertically centering your `block` level elements (`img`s while although `inline` function like `inline-block` [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/4u8jm4ng/3/)).

> You can easily vertically align any element, if you don't mind using the transform property, with a few lines of code.

```
.class {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```